# Mapping between stl C++ and C# containers

Tags: c#, c++, stl, containers

Can someone point out a good mapping between the usual C++ STL containers such as vector, list, map, set, multimap... and the C# generic containers?

I'm used to the former ones and somehow I've accustomed myself to express algorithms in terms of those containers. I'm having some hard time finding the C# equivalent to those.

Thank you!

Comment: You've stumbled across what is probably the biggest shortcoming on the .NET base class library... They're missing a lot of relatively common containers. And while LINQ does a decent job of replacing C++ iterators, it's still not as flexible (or efficient)

Comment: Closing this one in favor of a later https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659044/comparison-of-c-stl-collections-and-c-sharp-collections because that later one has a longer list of collection mappings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a **rough** equivalence:

1. `Dictionary<K,V>` <=> `unordered_map<K,V>`
2. `HashSet<T>` <=> `unordered_set<T>`
3. `List<T>` <=> `vector<T>`
4. `LinkedList<T>` <=> `list<T>`

The .NET BCL (base class library) does not have red-black trees (stl map) or priority queues (make_heap(), push_heap(), pop_heap()).

.NET collections don't use "iterators" the way C++ does. They all implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and can be iterated over using the "`foreach` statement". If you want to manually control iteration you can call "`GetEnumerator()`" on the collection which will return an `IEnumerator<T>` objet. `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()` is roughly equivalent to "++" on a C++ iterator, and "Current" is roughly equivalent to the pointer-deference operator ("*").

C# does have a language feature called "iterators". They are not the same as "iterator objects" in the STL, however. Instead, they are a language feature that allows for automatic implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`. See documentation for the `yield return` and `yield break` statements for more information.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you have C++ and Java slightly confused there. (Though the rest of your discussion seems right, all the classes you list on the right of the table are Java collections, not STL containers.)

Comment: I had the casing wrong, and I left out "_" in the hash stuff (they are non standard, but most compilers support them).

I updated the names.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a look at [STL/CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385954.aspx) which is

> ... is a packaging of
>   the Standard Template Library (STL), a
>   subset of the Standard C++ Library,
>   for use with C++ and the .NET
>   Framework common language runtime
>   (CLR). With STL/CLR, you can use all
>   the containers, iterators, and
>   algorithms of STL in a managed
>   environment.

Also, keep in mind that you can compile your existing C++/STL code with the **/clr** flag.

Comment: Do you have any experience with that? As I understand it, it only allows you to use STL-like code in managed C++. It doesn't provide a language-agnostic STL-alike implementation, does it? I'd love to have something like STL in C#. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This SorceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cstl) looks like an interesting resource for what your looking for.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a terrific direct mapping, since e.g. C++ set and map use comparators, whereas .Net HashSet and Dictionary use hash codes.