# Comparison of C++ STL collections and C# collections?

Tags: c#, c++, collections, stl

I'm still learning C# and was surprised to find out that a `List<T>` is much more like a `std::vector` than a `std::list`.  Can someone describe all the C# collections in terms of the STL (or if STL comparisons are difficult, standard conceptual data types with Wikipedia links?  I expect the reference would be widely useful.

A minimal list of collections of interest include (feel free to add others):

- Array
- List
- ArrayList
- HashTable
- Dictionary
- ListDictionary
- SortedDictionary
- SortedList
- Queue
- Stack

Edit: I just found this similar question that may be of interest: [Mapping between stl C++ and C# containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741054/mapping-between-stl-c-and-c-containers)

Comment: Unless you need to target .NET 1.x there's really no reason to bother with the non-generic types if you ask me.

Comment: LinkedList, HashSet, Lookup(usually referred to via the interface ILookup). I don't know STL, but i std::list is not like List<T> it is probably more like LinkedList<T>.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Which ones are non-generics?  Just the Array?

Comment: ArrayList, HashTable. In fact, any class in the System.Collections namespace (as opposed to System.Collections.Generic, which was added in .NET 2)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's what I've found (ignoring the old non-generic collections):

- `Array` - C array, though the .NET Array *can* have a non-zero starting index.
- [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) - [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) - [`unordered_map<Key, Data>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
- [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) - [`unordered_set<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)
- [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) - [`std::map<Key, Data>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)
- [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2) - equivalent to a `std::vector<T>` but keeping it ordered by using binary search + insert when adding elements.
- [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1) - [`std::set<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)
- [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) - [`std::queue<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)
- [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1) - [`std::stack<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)
- [`LinkedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1) - [`std::list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Notably missing from the .NET collections are the "multi-" variants, e.g., [`multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset), [`multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), etc. However, they have added a number of very useful threadsafe collections: the "Concurrent-" variants, e.g., [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2), [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1), etc.

Comment: you might want to replace `hash_map` with `unordered_map`, which, while technically still not *standard*, is included in TR1, and will be included in C++0x. The same us true for `hash_set`-> `unordered_set`. By the way, another missing variant is `std::deque`. As far a I know, there is no .NET equivalent.

Comment: So there's no equivalent to `std::list` and `std::deque`?

Comment: @kuhaku: There is no doubly-linked list. In practice, since .NET apps generally use reference types, `List<T>` (actually a vector) is usually sufficient. There is also no double-ended queue, and this is a more noticeable omission IMO. Again, `List<T>` is generally used as a replacement, which works OK since reference types prevail.

Comment: After I posted this I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx so LinkedList is new I assume?

Comment: Also, why would `List<T>` still be ok if you need to add and remove elements from anywhere in the container, wouldn't it sometimes cause reallocations?

Comment: @kuhaku: Sorry, my comment was wrong. As noted in my answer, `LinkedList<T>` is an equivalent to `std::list<T>`. (Though `LinkedList<T>` is very rarely used in practice). `List<T>` is a vector, so allocations are amortized, and due to the ubiquity of reference types, the actual amount of memory copies are low unless your collections are *extremely* large. In terms of performance, `List<T>` is pretty similar to `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: Extremely unfortunate that the geniuses at Microsoft chose to the name List<T> when the container is not a list. If you really want to confuse people for a long time to come, that is how you decide on names.