# C# equivalent of C++ Vector< Vector<string> > MegaVec;

Tags: c#, vector

The main idea is to have the functionality of `MegaVec[i][j]` to make accessing and indexing simple for use in randomization. I will be using this structure to make a "coherent" text generator of sorts.

I have failed to locate any documentation on vectors of vectors in C# thus far. Any and all input is welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: See [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) and in particular [Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# equivalent to a C++ Vector is List.

`Vector<Vector<string>>` would then be `List<List<String>>`. This object supports automatic resizing like Vector does.

Comment: Outside of local variables, one might use interfaces in the signature and List for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you "just need" a "vector-like" container, use `System.Generic.List<T>`. You can tell it to preallocate some space via overloaded constructor (initial 'capacity' ~ `reserve()`). Accessing i-th element/appending/popping is more-or-less the same as in vector - amortized O(1) on average, other interesting ops are O(n) in the worst case, and so on. Do not be fooled by the name of 'List' - it's not a list in the classic data structures meaning. The classic list is called a LinkedList - C# base class library has such class and that's the true linked-list with all the typical properties of the list like O(n) item access. Btw. If you look for a "map", it's called a Dictionary here..

edit: and also, have a handy cheat sheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659731/717732